# How to get all Set-Cookie headers with Postman

Tags: http-headers, postman

My app returns two Set-Cookie headers: JSESSIONID and AWSELB.

When I write test in Postman and use `postman.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` it only returns AWSELB.

Any idea how can I get JSESSIONID?

EDIT:
Accepted Answer solved it in one way, now I have same issue but with sending two headers with same key.
I should be able to send multiple 'Set-Cookie' headers, but when I do that it looks like only the last one is being sent, first one is overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that getResponseHeader contains only the last header, so it is not really useful when dealing with cookies.

I would rather suggest you try

> getResponseCookie

For example:

```
tests["Should contain JSESSIONID cookie"] = postman.getResponseCookie('JSESSIONID').value === 'abcdef';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Actually postman contains all headers under postman.response.headers
Its type is HeaderList. But it stores headers with type Array. And Header has key and value.

So you can loop through postman.response.headers and filter out what you need with either value or key

//filter by header key

```
pm.response.headers
.filter(header=>header.key.includes("whatever you are looking for"))
.map(f=>console.log( f.value))
```

//filter by header value

```
pm.response.headers
.filter(header=>header.value.includes("whatever you are looking for"))
.map(f=>console.log( f.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

i used below method to get cookies from response header,

```
const Cookie = require('postman-collection').Cookie;

const oResponseHeaders = pm.response.headers;
oResponseHeaders.filter(function(resHeader){
    //console.log("resHeader : ",resHeader);
    
    let bSetCookieExists = resHeader.key.includes("Set-Cookie");
    if(bSetCookieExists){
        console.log('cookie : ',resHeader.key.includes("Set-Cookie"));
        
        let  rawHeader = pm.response.headers.get("Set-Cookie");
        let myCookie = new Cookie(rawHeader);
        console.log("myCookie : ",myCookie.toJSON());
        console.log("myCookie name : ", myCookie.name);
        console.log("myCookie value : ", myCookie.value);
      
    }
    
   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The API seems to have changed again. Now it's something like

```js
pm.response.headers.get('Set-Cookie').
  split('; ').find(s=>s.startsWith('myCookieName='))?.split('=')[1]
```

get get the value of the cookie `myCookieName`.